# English clause word order

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, word-order, clauses

I found this sentence:

> I am convinced that not only could I control a group of people effectively, but the group would also benefit from my skills.

Why is this word order correct: "could I" (auxiliary verb + subject)? Which clause structure/rule is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used in this way, "not only" requires an auxiliary verb and [sub-aux inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion). Thus, for example, all of the following are correct:

> Not only could I control . . .

> Not only did I control . . .

> Not only was I controlling . . .

It won't work, however, with a non-auxiliary verb:

> *Not only controlled I . . .